# A numba compatible way of reshaping a 1d numpy array to a nd array with only the couple (n, d)

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am looking for any alternate way to write

```
arr_1d = np.zeros(d ** n)
arr_nd = arr_1d.reshape((d,) * n)
```

with a `@numba.jit(nopython=True)` decorator. (The rank `n` is not fixed so writing `(d,...,d)` is not a solution)

#### As an example:

```
from numba import njit, objmode

def tensor(series: np.ndarray, dim: int):
    n = int(np.log(len(series)) / np.log(dim))
    new_shape = (dim,) * n
    # new_shape = [dim] * n
    # new_shape = tuple([dim] * n)
    # with objmode(new_shape="UniTuple(dtype=np.int8, count="+str(n)+")"):
    #     new_shape = (dim,) * n
    return series.reshape(new_shape)

d = 2
n = 3
series = np.zeros(shape=d**n)

print(tensor(series=series, dim=d))
# [[[0. 0.]
#   [0. 0.]]
# 
#  [[0. 0.]
#   [0. 0.]]]

print(njit(tensor)(series=series, dim=d))
# Error (see below)
```

#### I tried different ways of writing the `new_shape` tuple:

The multiplication of tuples seems not to be implemented:

```
new_shape = (dim,) * n
# TypingError: No implementation of function Function(<built-in function mul>) found for signature
```

The multiplication of lists *is* implemented, but a list does not work in the `reshape` method:

```
new_shape = [dim] * n
# TypingError: Invalid use of BoundFunction(array.reshape for array(float64, 1d, C)) with parameters (list(int64)<iv=None>)
```

As stated in the documentation, but worth a shot, `tuple()` is not implemented in numba:

```
new_shape = tuple([dim] * n)
# TypingError: No implementation of function Function(<class 'tuple'>) found for signature:
```

So I tried `objmode` but I don't understand it enough, so I can not make it work...

```
with objmode(new_shape="UniTuple(np.int8,"+str(n)+")"):
    new_shape = (dim,) * n
# CompilerError: Error handling objmode argument 'new_shape'. The value must be a compile-time constant either as a non-local variable or a getattr expression that refers to a Numba type.
```

There might not be a solution yet, but if I missed something, I'd be delighted to receive any advice !

Thanks

Comment: I think it's not even possible to have varying array shapes as a return value. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70598981/14277722) might be helpful, but it's about a different topic regarding `tuples`.

Comment: You can also make `new_shape` by `np.ones(n, dtype = np.int64) * dim` but that doesn't work either, but it's a different error at least (`Invalid use of BoundFunction(array.reshape for array(float64, 1d, C)) with parameters (array(int64, 1d, C))`)

Comment: Generally you can't do this within the Numba function. The array dimensionality has to be known at compile time and can't be changed at runtime. But there is a possible workaround. You can use a generator function to get  functions for all needed array dims. In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59356461/4045774 I used a generator function to get optimized matrix-matrix multiplication, depended on array shapes. You probably can do quite the same for different array-dims. Of course another possible solution would be to do the reshape outside of Numba.